# Cannot set textwidth through modeline in Python files

Tags: modeline

I am trying to set the `textwidth` option in a `python` file and I added the following line at the end of my `.py` file:

```
# vim: set textwidth=120
```

However:

- `:set textwidth?`,
- `:echo &l:textwidth` and
- `:echo &textwidth`
  they all return `78` instead of the expected `120`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a valid modeline?

Comment: I missed the final colon, as per the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the trailing colon (`:`)

You have to do:

```python
# vim: set textwidth=120:
```

Or:

```python
# vim: textwidth=120
```

Remark: the `set:` variant has been introduced because the other variant will parse the entire line as a list of options , preventing the use of comments of the kind `/*   */` , where the `set:` variant will only consider the text between `set`  and `:`. That is the reason why the `:` is important (see: [Modelline magic](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Modeline_magic))

More information with `:help modeline`

Comment: Well spotted. I totally missed that. However, I think the ':' is called a "colon", not "column". I'd edit the typo myself but with the little reputation I have, I would need to change at least 6 characters and wait for peer review... \*sigh*

Comment: Thanks. Some one did it for you :-)

Comment: I seem to be completely useless today. Have an upvote, it's the least I can do.